# Running loop synchronously in python

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, synchronous

I have a block of code, that crawls an infinite height website `(Like FACEBOOK)`.

The Python selenium script asks the page javascript to go to the bottom of the page in order to load page further down. But eventually it happens that the loop runs asynchronously and the website's rate-limiter blocks the script.

I need the page to wait for the page to load first and then continue, but i failed in doing that.

The following things are what i have tried till now.

The code goes as follows :

```
while int(number_of_news) != int(len(news)) :
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight/2, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("news-text")
    print(len(news))
```

The output is something like

[image]

Which i interpreted as the loop being executed multiple times when the value is `43, 63... and so on`.

I also tried making it recursive, but the result is still the same. The recursive code is as follows :

```
def call_news(_driver, _news, _number_of_news):
    _driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    _news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("news-text")
    print(len(_news))
    if int(len(_news)) != int(number_of_news) :
        call_news(_driver, _news, _number_of_news)
    else :
        return _news
```

Any kind of tip is appreciated.

Comment: After each scroll do you have some element on which you can setup a wait to be visible after the new news items are loaded. For example an instruction text to scroll more or some unique class for the last news item etc etc...

Comment: @Grasshopper The problem is i dont have a unique class/id name upon scrolling. All i have is elements of a particular class name "news-text"

Comment: How about waiting for all the elements with that class after each scroll? Dont know about exact method in python but in java you can wait for visibility or presence of all elements for a locator.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `page_load_timeout` to make the driver wait for the page to load

```
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
```

Another option is to wait for the number of elements to change

```
current_number_of_news = 0
news = []
while int(number_of_news) != int(len(news)) :
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight/2, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    while (current_number_of_news == len(news)) :
        news = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("news-text")
    current_number_of_news = len(news)
    print(len(news))
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more.

Comment: @CodeGirl This will make the driver wait up to 10 seconds for the page to load. You define it once after the driver creation.

Comment: Not exactly... This means that if the page does not load within 10 secs it will throw an error. So if the page is loaded within 10 secs it will not wait for that time. Plus this will not apply to an asynchronous call like ones initiated by scrolling.

Comment: @Grasshopper Please read again my comment. I didn't say it will wait the all time.

Comment: @Guy But the page is already loaded... elements keep adding to the page upon scrolling. Like Facebook : Posts keep on adding upon scrolling down. Page was already loaded initially.

Comment: @MegaMind_2 I added another option